# How to deserialize a dictionary from a JSON file when I know what is in the file?

Tags: c#

I am trying to write dictionary to a .json file and then read it from this file. I managed to serialize it and write to a file, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong when I try to read it. Visual Studio writes the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<\string, object>' An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).

I tried the following:

```
Dictionary<string, object> last_record = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

or

```
object last_record;
```

do not help.

Here is the code I use:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;

Dictionary<string, object> my_database = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Dictionary<string, string> my_record = new Dictionary<string, string>();

my_record.Add("Name", "John");
my_record.Add("Surname", "Smith");
my_record.Add("Country", "UK");

my_database.Add("ID", "01");
my_database.Add("Person", my_record);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(my_database);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:\\Test.json", true, Encoding.ASCII);
sw.WriteLine(json);
sw.Close();

//
// In another part of the program:
//
string last_line;
last_line = File.ReadLines("D:\\Test.json").Last();

// next line produces the error:    
Dictionary<string, object> last_record = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(last_line);
last_ID = last_record["ID"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the generic variant from the converter, you use:

```
var last_record = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,object>>(last_line);
```

Otherwise, you get the non-generic version that returns `object`.

Comment: Yep, that was obvious. Thank you!